# C# error with function and textboxes as a parameter

Tags: c#, parameters

I have a problem with writing a function and passing it a parameter.

My problem is that I've created my function called `mySum`. I've shown the code below.

Note: I've used two text boxes to get the values from the user, and the function should add those two values and show it in `MessageBox`.

```
void mySum(int a, int b)
{
    int ans;
    ans = a + b;
    MessageBox.Show(ans.ToString());
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Here i want to ass two text boxes values as given below.
    mySum(txtbox1.text,txtbox2.text); //Here it shows me the error
}
```

Comment: Did you read what the error actually said? It should be clear as daylight.

Comment: covert txtbox1.Text to int as mySum takes int args

Comment: Better yet, instead of just converting to an int, use System.Int32.TryParse() to ensure the data is in a valid format, and invalid formats are handled properly.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is expecting `integer` as the argument.But you are passing a string ( Text property returns string). So convert to it.

```
mySum(Convert.ToInt32(txtbox1.Text),Convert.ToInt32(txtbox2.Text));
```

You may check the null values/ Is valid numeric value, before converting, otherwise the ToInt32 function will throw an exception. Use `Int32.TryParse`

```
int value1=0;
int value2=0;
int result;

if (!Int32.TryParse(txtbox1.Text, out value1))
{   
   MessageBox.Show("Not valid number");
   return;
}  
if (!Int32.TryParse(txtbox2.Text, out value2))
{   
   MessageBox.Show("Not valid number");
   return;
}

mySum(value1,value2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Parse the textbox values to integers:

```
mySum(int.Parse(txtbox1.text),int.Parse(txtbox2.text));
```

Add approriate error handling.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

          mySum(Int32.Parse(txtbox1.text), Int32.Parse(txtbox2.text));          

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply do like this:

```
int mySum(string a, string b)
    {
       return Convert.ToInt32(a) + Convert.ToInt32(b);
    }
```

In your code behind file, call above function like this:

```
    MessageBox.Show(mySum(txtbox1.Text,txtbox2.Text)..ToString());
```

Comment: Sorry, this wont compile :) Copy/paste, bad mmkay! (you actually have 2 errors)

Comment: I've updated the answer....Now, it should work...

Comment: Oops, did not see that actually :) You didn't fix the 2 errors I mentioned though.

Comment: Sorry....Missed to check the return type along with Text property....okay,Now I'll debug my code....

Comment: While writing above code, I hadn't compiled the code so it happens.....Thanx for spotting the mistake....

Answer (score 2):

The problem is thsat txtBox1.Text isn't stored as an int, it's stored as a string.  You need to use System.Int32.TryParse to ***safely*** see if the text is a string and convert it to an int.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     int firstInt = -1;
     int secondInt = -1;

    if(!System.Int32.TryParse(txtbox1.Text, out firstInt)
    {
       MessageBox.Shw("Invalid value in Textbox 1");
       return; // Stop procesing
    }
    if(!System.Int32.TryParse(txtbox2.Text, out secondInt)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Invalid value in Textbox 2");
       return; // Stop procesing
    }
    //Here i want to add the values from two text boxes values as given below.
     mySum(firstInt, secondInt); //Here it shows me the error . Please help me.           
 }
```

Comment: I wonder if this counts as pair programming.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's better to teach new programmers the simple way first, and then to elaborate on best practices, once they understand the basics.

Answer (score 1):

you're passing `string`s to a function expecting `int`s try

```
mySum(int.Parse(txtbox1.text),int.Parse(txtbox2.text))
```

Answer (score 1):

`Textbox.Text` property returns string. And in your function declaration you are passing two integers. So you need to convert strings to integers.

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't have an implicit conversion from String to Int32 so if your method takes an int parameter, you have to convert the value to an int before passing it in.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good way to do this.

I recommend this instead:

```
public int mySum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

And then on your event, execute the following code:

```
var t1 = int.Parse(txtbox1.text);
var t2 = int.Parse(txtbox2.text);
MessageBox.Show(mySum(t1,t2))
```

...keep in mind, this will have problems if your text boxes aren't actually holding integer values.  You can check out `int.TryParse()` for a more robust solution.

Comment: Or you can just use databinding and be done with it ;p

Comment: @leppie: Meh.  I don't know much about databinding in windows apps (I'm ASP.NET mainly) but I think I'd prefer to keep the validation logic out of the UI.  Personal preference.